# GEB not finding elements

Tags: jquery, selenium, spock, geb

i am very fresh to GEB and i am trying to create a very simple test case using spock and selenium.

The application is a single page application using OJET

HTML CODE

```
<div class="oj-hybrid-padding">
    <div id="dashboardTitleDiv">
        <h1>Dashboard Content Area</h1>
    </div>
    .....
</div>
```

GEB Page

```
class ISSDashboardPage extends Page {
    static url = "?root=dashboard"
    static at = { $("div#dashboardTitleDiv>h1").text() == "Dashboard Content Area" }
}
```

The Groovy Test

```
class NavigateToWorkspaceSpec extends GebSpec {
    def "can navigate to Workspace"() {
        when: to ISSDashboardPage
        then: waitFor(25){at ISSDashboardPage}
    }
}
```

For some reason that i dont understand, the selector on the Page "at" is not working. This is the error i am getting:

```
Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 10.763 sec <<< FAILURE! - in NavigateToWorkspaceSpec
can navigate to Workspace(NavigateToWorkspaceSpec)  Time elapsed: 10.39 sec  <<< FAILURE!
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.powerassert.PowerAssertionError:
$("div#dashboardTitleDiv>h1").text() == "Dashboard Content Area"
|                             |      |
[]                            null   false
        at NavigateToWorkspaceSpec.can navigate to Workspace(NavigateToWorkspaceSpec.groovy:8)


Results :

Failed tests:
  NavigateToWorkspaceSpec.can navigate to Workspace:8->GebSpec.methodMissing:56 $("div#dashboardTitleDiv>h1").text() == "Dashboard Content Area"
|                             |      |
[]                            null   false

Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

if the selector is just "$(h1).text() it finds the text of the first "h1" element

```
$("h1").text() == "Dashboard Content Area"
|       |      |
|       |      false
|       Inside Sales
```

Can anyone spot what is wrong?
I notice that partial part of the page was not yet rendered (actually i can't see yet the  i am expecting to see). But i was expecting that the  waitFor on the test would waint at least 25 seconds till that selector to be resolved.

Thank you very much.

Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure

- the `at` checker is not being cached,
- the element is optional and
- just integrate the waiting right into the page element in order to avoid the `waitFor` in your test. (But hey, 25 seconds is really long. Is your page really so slow?)

```java
static at = { dynamicH1.text() == "Dashboard Content Area" }

static content = {
  dynamicH1(required: false, wait: 25, cache: false) { $("div#dashboardTitleDiv>h1") }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much kriegaex. It worked perfectly with no complains. Actually if i just add the wait on the definition of dynamicH1 is enough. The value was too high because i just wanted to make sure there is enough time for the page to load. Now i can reduce it.

Thank you a lot

Comment: @kriegaex can you explain why this element should be required:false? Why should we allow the test to continue if the page isn't fully loaded yet?

Comment: Like the OP said above, you don't strictly need it in this situation. In my local test case I emulated a more complex `at` checker like `foo() || bar() || zot()`, though, i.e. whichever of the three dynamic parts  of the page were available first, the at checker would return true and stop blocking the test. Depending on some configuration such as user rights, some parts of the page would not be available at all. Without `required: false` the test would yield exceptions because of unavailable elements. Sorry, I did not copy the full page and test here, I was just extending my own old test case.

Comment: im trying to understand if the only check in his at block is dynamicH1 and we then mark it req:false, the test could continue past this at check even if the page hasnt loaded, causing failure down the line no?

Comment: Just give it a try, I cannot see your code. But basically for `required: true` (default) your `at` check in the test would yield `WaitTimeoutException: condition did not pass in 25.0 seconds`, for `required: false` it would just return `null` for the page, yielding `Condition not satisfied: at DateFormatTimeZonePage | null`. So even then the test fails here, only with a less messy error message. Do whatever is right in your situation, but as I said: Try for yourself, don't just theorise here with me. :-)